# WSDL not building correctly when extension and elements are used in the same object

Tags: soap, wsdl, element, jaxbelement

Whenever I try to build the wsdl file it won't correctly build the object when its inherited and has a sequence of elements listed. For example...

```
<xs:complexType name="Triangle">
 <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>blah blah blah </xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
 <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Shape">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="angle1"/>
          <xs:element ref="angle2"/>
          <xs:element ref="angle3"/>
        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>`
```

This builds the java Triangle class with the extension base only and none of the 3 elements listed above.  However if i remove the extension, the 3 elements populate after building the wsdl file.  Its only when I have both the extension tag and element tag that the element stuff doesn't appear.  Anyone have insight as to what is going on?

Comment: Could you add definition of `Shape`,all 3  `Angles`?

Comment: it looks like it has to do something with the mvn build because it builds fine in SoapUI, currently using apache cxf 3.2.4.  Just can't figure out why its not working.